# Elastic - Search across object without key specification

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with hundreds of millions docs and each of them has an object "histogram" with values for each day:

```
   "_source": {
      "proxy": {
        "histogram": {
          "2017-11-20": 411,
          "2017-11-21": 34,
          "2017-11-22": 0,
          "2017-11-23": 2,
          "2017-11-24": 1,
          "2017-11-25": 2692,
          "2017-11-26": 11673
        }
      }
   }
```

And I need one of two solutions:

1. Find docs where any value inside histogram object is greater then XX
2. Find docs where avg of values in histogram object is greater then XX

In point 1 I can use range query, but I must specify exactly name of field (i.e. proxy.histogram.2017-11-20). And wildcard version (proxy.histogram.*) doesnot work.

In point 2 I found in ES only average aggregation, but I don't want aggregation of these fields after query (because large of data), I want to only search these docs.

Comment: I think, your data set should change as separated docs for each histogram data. And you can use aggregation to generate real-time histogram data. After changes, You can get higher than XX and greater than XX of average values, easily. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, this is one way how to solve the problem. But its required a very long time (many days) for regenerate it and also it will change completely how i now access data (this proxy histogram is one of a lot parts of doc). This is reasson why i try find the way how to solve it with current dataset.

Comment: As I know, You can not fetch specific field of docs with the only query (I know there is "_source" or "fields" feature. But they are not solving this problem.). You should use script/plugin, or you should fetch the docs with multiple queries on your app logic for any criteria and then merge the result docs of data. And this will be time for your effort and resultset.

Comment: yes, i'm trying do it with script, and its success:

`{
   "query": {
     "match_all": {}
   },
   "script_fields": {
     "min_visits": {
       "script": {
         "lang": "painless",
         "source": "def visits=0; for (p in params['_source'].proxy.histogram.entrySet()){ if (p.value>1000) visits=1;} return visits;"
       }
     }
   }
}`

but, problem is that i did find any way how to use created fields in query or filter :(

Comment: You can get results of the first query then use this resultset to create a new query. But I had said before. These solutions will cause other problems and be more problematic. For example, right now your servers will be tired like you. I think, in the end, you should change your mapping.